# How to call a package added previously

Tags: packages

I'm using the package `mcode` to show matlab code in my thesis. This package requires the `xcolor` package so it automatically loads it. My problem is that I have to call the `table` option in the `xcolor` package but when I call it after `mcode` I get an error  because it was previously called in `mcode`. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: so is `mcode` loaded by your _class_ ?

Comment: You should have a look at the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; it improves upon `mcode` in many ways. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891), for instance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
```

before `\documentclass{...}` and no need of loading `xcolor` by yourself.

Or add the option `table` to document class itself:

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
```

Comment: Yeah tahnks so much...it works...I will accept your ans soon

Answer (score 12):

Just use

```
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

before loading `mcode`